# How this onclick event works and what it mean?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

There is link on a webpage, clicking on the link opens a asp.net page.

Inspecting that element, i can see the onclick event of the link says "_ctl00_ql.newWorkItem("Our Case");return false;"

I don't understand what this means and how it calls a that webpage. I know that its ClientIDMode is auto as it start with prefix ct100.

UPDATE:

I am trying to open the site in WebBrowser Control and want to redirect to the page which is triggered by that link. Since I can not call the page directly as it contains a unique GUID every time page is opened.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Check the code for `_ctl00_ql.newWorkItem` in your browser console.. You might be able to figure it out.

Comment: You can search for `_ctl00_ql.newWorkItem` in your browser console and find a function with that name.

Comment: You need to show the code for `newWorkItem` for this to be answerable. Quite possibly once you've looked at that code you'll be able to answer it yourself.